# CSS compilers in GAE Python

Tags: python, css, google-app-engine

Are there any quick light python libraries to use compiled CSS that is converted to CSS on-the-fly?

Comment: What do you mean by 'compiled css'? Is it a thing like SASS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **CleverCSS**:

http://sandbox.pocoo.org/clevercss/
Or the Python port of **LessCSS**: http://code.google.com/p/lesscss-python/

The Python version of LessCSS is quite new though, it doesn't seem to be all that mature yet.